# NSTableViewCell.ImageView Setting Position?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a NSTableViewCell which has a ImageView within the cell.

What is needed to control the position of the image within the cell using code?

Comment: are you using subclass of NSTextFieldCell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using subclass of `NSTextFieldCell`([ImageAndTextCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DragNDropOutlineView/Listings/ImageAndTextCell_m.html)). you can control positon of image in
`- (NSRect)imageRectForBounds:(NSRect)cellFrame` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom cell...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ImageOnRightCell";

    UIImageView *photo;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

        photo = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225.0, 0.0, 80.0, 45.0)]];
        photo.tag = PHOTO_TAG;
        photo.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:photo];
    } else {
        photo = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:PHOTO_TAG];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

This will look like it....
[image]
or u can read this link....
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Answer (score 0):

instead of default TableViewCell, create your own custom tableViewCell and position it according to your need.